# Cannot save special characters like "ñ" in MySQL Administrator Database using vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

Can someone help me on how to save "ñ" in MySQL database using vb.net?

I have created a program in vb.net and the backend i used is MySQL Administrator database which resides in another pc. So the development pc i used act as the client pc. I noticed that everytime I saved data from the client to server pc using the program, the text that contains 'ñ' was truncated. For e.g. the last name i saved was 'Añovert', after I saved the data to database it becomes 'A'. The character ñ and the letters following it wasn't saved. The charset i used was utf8 and the collation was utf_general_ci.

What should I do to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how are you saving the data? Are you running a insert? Please give a little more detail.

Comment: yes. I am using Insert query through stored procedure. My problem is I am saving a pdf filename to the database and sometimes the filename contains special character like 'ñ'. But I wasn't able to open it everytime I retrieve the file I have saved because the filename was truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your database administration with MySQL WorkBench for example, put the Engine to InnoDB and the collation to utf8-utf8_general_ci.

Comment: I have already changed the engine to InnoDB and the collation to utf8-utf8_general_ci but there's no changes. Is there any other possible way? If you don't mind. Thanks :-)

Answer (score -1):

ñ is on iso-8859-1 not utf you do that and check if its fixed xD

Comment: `ñ` is representable in UTF-8